# UIGestureReconizer Crash - Unrecognized Gesture Error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swipe

Hi so my GestureReconizers crash my app when I use them. I get an error saying that it received an unrecognized gesture and I get a SIGABRT error too. I've tried looking at other posts and theres been no fix yet. 
[BTW, this is in my didMoveToView section]

```
var upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes;"))
var downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     Selector("handleSwipes;"))
var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes;"))
var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes;"))

    upSwipe.direction = .Up
    downSwipe.direction = .Down
    rightSwipe.direction = .Right
    leftSwipe.direction = .Left

    view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.direction == .Left {
            msgText("Left")
        }
        if sender.direction == .Right {
            msgText("Right")
        }
        if sender.direction == .Up {
            msgText("Up")
        }
        if sender.direction == .Down {
            msgText("Down")
        }

       }
```

I'm also trying to have the gestures only active when map.zPosition == 100. So if you know a good way to do that, that'd be awesome.

Comment: try Selector("handleSwipes") instead Selector("handleSwipes;") etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use colon "`:`" for handle Swipes not semi colon "`;`"

That was the reason your code was crashing

> Here is your fixed code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    var downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

    leftSwipe.direction = .Left
    rightSwipe.direction = .Right
    upSwipe.direction = .Up
    downSwipe.direction = .Down

    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)

}
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .Left) {
        print("Swipe Left")

    }

    if (sender.direction == .Right) {
        print("Swipe Right")
    }
    if (sender.direction == .Up) {
        print("Swipe Up")
    }
    if (sender.direction == .Down) {
        print("Swipe Down")
    }
}
```

> Output

[image: ouput]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use semicolon on selector,

This `"handleSwipes;"` should be `"handleSwipes:"`

Comment: Also, you can get rid of `Selector()` and just use `"handleSwipes:"` for the selector.

Comment: "handleSwipes" ??? there are no other parameters there ... so the : should not be there, right?

Comment: @user3441734  `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is the parameter